# Deploying a next.js app to Azure Web App: Files not found

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy a next.js (with typescript) app on Azure, using Bitbucket pipelines.
In my pipeline, I build the next.js, with build config the following:

```js
// next.config.js

/**@type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
   output: 'standalone',
}
module.exports = nextConfig
```

Then, I deploy it to Azure

```yaml
    - step: &deploy-preview
        caches:
          - node
          - nextcache
        script:
          - zip -r files.zip .next/ public/
          - pipe: microsoft/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.0.4
            variables:
              AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
              AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
              AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
              AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP
              AZURE_APP_NAME: $AZURE_APP_NAME
              ZIP_FILE: 'files.zip'
        artifacts:
          - "files.zip"
```

If I take a look at the artifacts folder it does contain all the files I expect.
On the Azure web App i have the startup command node `.next/standalone/server.js`

It does startup a next.js server, but it cannot find the files under .next/static. In my console i see that they are all 404. However, the files are present.

Can anyone give me some insights about what is going on, and what i could possibly do in order to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue. I solved it, after digging through the docs of Next.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output#automatically-copying-traced-files

Here, it states that for the standalone config:

> This minimal server **does not copy the public** or .next/static folders by default as these should ideally be handled by a CDN instead, **although these folders can be copied to the standalone/public and standalone/.next/static folders manually**, after which server.js file will serve these automatically.

If you develop locally, your local machine will act as this CDN. But on Azure, the web app does not act as a CDN, so it's important to copy these files over.
This can be done in the bitbucket script.

An example of a bitbucket script:

```
image: node:18

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &deploy-production
        name: 'Deploy'
        deployment: Production
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install zip
          - "mkdir .next/standalone/.next/static"
          - "cp -r .next/static/* .next/standalone/.next/static"
          - "mkdir .next/standalone/public"
          - "cp -r public/* .next/standalone/public"
          - zip -r standalone.zip .next/* 
          - pipe: microsoft/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.0.4
            variables:
              AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
              AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
              AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
              AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: 'frontend'
              AZURE_APP_NAME: $AZURE_APP_NAME
              ZIP_FILE: 'standalone.zip'
        artifacts:
          - "standalone.zip"
pipelines:
  # Build, test and deploy on master branch.
  branches:
    master:
      - step: *deploy-production
```

Additional config:

1. I chose Node 18 LTS on Linux servers as the chosen runtime environment.
2. The startup command under Settings > Configuration > General Settings is `node ./next/standalone/server.js`.
3. If .env variables are introduced, configure them on Azure under Configuration > Application Settings.

Comment: Can you provide the full steps from your bitbucket pipeline? I would really love to see an example? Also is there anything specific you had to configure on the Azure side? Like within the App Service?

Comment: Hi @searc-learn, I've added my configs!